# ClickOnce Application Install - Security Warning

Tags: c#, deployment, warnings, clickonce, code-signing-certificate

I have a clickonce application that is deployed on the website (say, http://example.com) and users will download the setup.exe file of my published application from that website and install the application on their computer.

**I have signed the ClickOnce manifests of my application with the Certificate issued by GoDaddy for my company.**

But, the User still get the following Application Security Warning when they try to install my application. Is there a way around so that this security warning will not be shown at all?

Any help will be appreciated.

[image: Click Once Application Install - Security Warning]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, you have to follow the steps in the MSDN-library ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996418.aspx)):

> When a ClickOnce application is being launched on a user's desktop the
>   first time, the .NET Framework runtime will first check to ensure that
>   the application manifests have not been tampered with since they were
>   signed with whatever publisher certificate was used for signing. If
>   they pass that check, the runtime will then look into the Trusted Root
>   Certification Authority store and see if the certificate for the
>   issuer of the publisher's certificate is installed in that store. It
>   will then look at who the publisher on the certificate is, and see if
>   their certificate is in the Trusted Publishers store. **If those two
>   things are true, then *by default* the user will not be prompted**, and
>   the application will be granted whatever privileges are specified in
>   the application manifest file.

As long as the end user hasn't modified his notification settings, the prompt won't show up.

Comment: I think it can also show up for three other reasons, right?  Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58774764/how-to-avoid-security-warning-due-to-machine-access-on-clickonce-app-install