# How to use an EV code signing certificate with a ClickOnce Installer

Tags: visual-studio, certificate, clickonce

I purchased an EV signing certificate but since I can't sign the manifest with it since it isn't an exe. I can sign the exes (Setup and application) using signtool and my EV certificate but when running the ClickOnce, I get a warning saying the manifest isn't signed. However, if I do it that way, once it is installed I don't get any SmartScreen warnings.
I was able to sign the manifest with an OV certificate and that signs all of the files in the manifest BUT, then I get SmartScreen warnings.
If anyone has any experience signing ClickOnce installers with an EV certificate I would love to hear how they did it.
I am using Visual Studio 2022l
Thanks

Comment: Does this help? https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1225324/How-to-Sign-ClickOnce-Deployment-if-ClickOnce-Code

Comment: @DanielFisherlennybacon Thanks for that article. It looks promising. I will give it a go tomorrow.

Comment: Hi, @RyanH. Any updates on the question? Is your problem solved? If not, you could try to see if the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39539247/17722391) and [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770710/how-do-you-apply-digicert-ev-certificate-to-clickonce-application)help you.

Comment: @HuiLiu-MSFT I haven't had a chance to try and apply the document that  suggested yet but plan to ASAP.

Comment: Hi, @RyanH.  Ok, feel free to come back if you have an update.