# VSTO - Unable to deploy an application

Tags: excel, visual-studio, deployment, vsto, clickonce

I am creating an Excel document level add-in in Visual Studio 2013 but am having trouble deploying it.

The application runs on my computer no problem. It also runs on another computer I have that has Visual Studio installed but when I try and install it on a computer that doesn't have Visual Studio installed I get the below error message.

[image]

I have been unable to find the exact route of the problem. I have tried unclicking the Sign ClickOnce Deployment check box but to no avail.

I also tried using InstallShield (similar security issues) but would prefer to use ClickOnce.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you only get this warning? Can you install the application when you open the `Details`? Can you show us the `Details`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by details.

Comment: The `Details >>`-button.

Comment: The one in your screenshot...

Comment: LOL. OK, I have updated the question with the full image.

Comment: BTW, I get that the end-user can trust the document but I want to get the app to deploy without the user needing to do that.

Comment: Well, my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16040775/2132796) might help you. If not, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand what you wrote in your answer but I don't know how to implement certification in my application.